Pytube: Can't download certain resolutions
Im doing a script to download video and audio from youtube, for now, im having a problem with my video download script, there it is:
def VideoDownload_mp4(url, res):
    try:
        yt = pytube.YouTube(url)
        folder = "YouTube Videos"
        video = yt.streams.get_by_resolution(resolution=res)
        video.download(folder)
        print("downloaded.")
    except Exception as e:
        print(f"Error: {e}")

Example entries:
url = "https://youtu.be/YEqWLCBrgic?si=Z245EINTenbGqasr"
res = "720p"
I have another script to get the resolutions the video has:
def GetVideoQuality(url):
    yt = pytube.YouTube(url)
    base_list = []
    for stream in yt.streams:
        resolution = stream.resolution
        bitrate = stream.bitrate
        base_list.append({'resolution':resolution, 'bitrate':bitrate})
    
    new_dict = {}
    fixed_list = []

    for diccionario in base_list:
        resolution = diccionario['resolution']
        bitrate = diccionario['bitrate']
        if resolution is not None:
            if resolution not in new_dict:
                new_dict[resolution] = bitrate
                fixed_list.append(diccionario.copy())
            else:
                if bitrate > new_dict[resolution]:
                    new_dict[resolution] = bitrate
                    fixed_list.remove([d for d in fixed_list if d['resolution'] == resolution][0])
                    fixed_list.append(diccionario.copy())

    return fixed_list

So, lets say the video has ['1080p', '720p', '480p'], I choose one of those from a main script and send it to VideoDownload_mp4().
The problem is that some of those resolutions dont let me download it, giving me the error: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'download'.
That is strange cuz, for example, I can download 1080p without any problem, but don't let me download 480p.
Im missing something in the download script?
Sorry if I misspelled something, my english is not good.
I want to be able to download X video with any resolution it has, but some of those resolutions dont let me download.

try:
def VideoDownload_mp4(url:str, res:str, folder:str="YouTube Videos"):
    try:
        video = YouTube(url)
        video.streams.filter(res=res).first().download(folder)
        print(f"Downloaded {video.title}.mp4")
    except Exception as e:
        print(f"Error: {e}")

Here you have the full code:
from pytube import YouTube

def VideoDownload_mp4(url:str, res:str, folder:str="YouTube Videos"):
    try:
        video = YouTube(url)
        video.streams.filter(res=res).first().download(folder)
        print(f"Downloaded {video.title}.mp4")
    except Exception as e:
        print(f"Error: {e}")

VideoDownload_mp4("https://youtu.be/YEqWLCBrgic?si=Z245EINTenbGqasr", "480p")

It should works well, good luck.

No funciona, en primer lugar, no se puede declarar video = YouTube(url), porque YouTube no está definido, por eso se hace al inicio yt = pytube.YouTube(url), si no declaro video al principio, no puedo hacer streams.filter, y tampoco podría hacerlo si uso el get_by_resolution, ya que en el filtro estaría agregando la resolución, me parece.

Para esto es from pytube import YouTube así te ahorras poner pytube.YouTube y solo debes poner YouTube.

Hey BunnyProgrammer, welcome to SO! Please note that the main language here is English. I would encourage you to translate your answer into English.

It works, but at the same time it doesnt.
It lets me download all the qualityS the videos has, but they dont have audio, ok, let me explain well:

means I can download it normally


means I cant download it, I get the error
$ means I can download it, but it has not audio
For the same video, with my code:


720p
-$ 480p
360p
-$ 240p
-$ 144p

So its like, certain qualitys of a certain video are not available for download, idk why

In the docs, says that sometimes the stream has both or only video/audio.
Source here.
A partial solution could be download only streams with both video and audio (with the parameter progressive=True), but then you can't select the quality video.
video.streams.filter(progressive=True).first().download()

If you want the other qualities, you should merge audio and video streams, with for example ffmpeg. You have to install "ffmpeg-python" library. It takes some time if quality is high. Example:
from pytube import YouTube
import ffmpeg

yt = YouTube('https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YEqWLCBrgic')
yt_video = yt.streams.filter(only_video=True, mime_type="video/mp4").order_by('bitrate').desc().first().download(filename="video.mp4")
yt_audio = yt.streams.filter(only_audio=True, mime_type="audio/mp4").order_by('bitrate').desc().first().download(filename="audio.mp4")

video = ffmpeg.input(yt_video)
audio = ffmpeg.input(yt_audio)

ffmpeg.output(video, audio, 'final_file.mp4').run()

